# In p5.js, how can you make drawingContext only affect one shape?

Tags: javascript, canvas, p5.js

```
drawingContext.shadowBlur = 50;
  drawingContext.shadowColor = color("#F8B988")
  noStroke()
  fill("#f4d402");
  circle(width/2, height*0.60, 100);
  fill("black")
  rect(0, height*.60, 0, width)
```

How can I make drawingContext only affect the circle and not the rect?

I tried putting rect in a different function, but it still didn't fix. :(

Answer (score 1):

Use `push()` and `pop()`.
Quoting docs:

> The push() function saves the current drawing style settings and
> transformations, while pop() restores these settings. Note that these
> functions are always used together. They allow you to change the style
> and transformation settings and later return to what you had.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  push(); 
  drawingContext.shadowBlur = 50;
  drawingContext.shadowColor = color("#F8B988");
  noStroke();
  fill("#f4d402");
  circle(width / 2, height * 0.6, 100);
  pop(); 
  fill("black");
  rect(0, height * 0.6, width, height);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```